# How to set ANT_HOME on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, ant, environment-variables

It looks like Ubuntu uses `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.pam_profile`, `/etc/environment`, and `/etc/profile` in very similar ways. I'd like to be able to add a configuration to one of these (which ever is the appropriate one) to set `ANT_HOME` to be the absolute path to my Ant installation's root directory (happens to be `/opt/apache/ant/1.8.4/apache-ant-1.8.4/`). This variable needs to be "honored" as is any normal env var, where I can open up a terminal and `echo` it at any time. It would also be nice if I could set this in such a way for Java to read it in at runtime from a `System.getProperty("")` call.

- Which file do I use?
- How do I actually set it so that it meets my requirements above?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers here!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**For global settings, system-wide environment variables**

- Use `/etc/environment`
- don't use `/etc/profile`, or `/etc/bash.bashrc`

From [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) page :

> `/etc/environment` [...] is
>   specifically meant for system-wide
>   environment variable settings. It is
>   not a script file, but rather consists
>   of assignment expressions, one per
>   line. Specifically, this file stores
>   the system-wide locale and path
>   settings.

Using `/etc/profile` is a very Unix-y way to go, but its functionality is greatly reduced under Ubuntu.   It exists only to point to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and to collect entries from `/etc/profile.d` .

On my system, the only interesting entry entry in profile.d is `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` .

**For local or per-user settings**

A previous version of the Ubuntu page recommended `~/.pam_environment` , but the page currently suggests that if that doesn't work, you should use

- > `~/.profile` - This is probably the
  >   best file for placing environment
  >   variable assignments in, since it gets
  >   executed automatically by the
  >   DisplayManager during the startup
  >   process desktop session as well as by
  >   the login shell when one logs-in from
  >   the textual console.
- `~/.bash_profile` or `~./bash_login` - If one of these exists, bash executes it instead of "~/.profile" when bash is started as a login shell. Bash will prefer `~/.bash_profile` to  `~/.bash_login`. [...] These files won't influence a graphical session by default."
- `~/.bashrc` - "... may be the easiest place to set variables".

Answer (score 6):

First, open bash file with following code.

xxx@xxx-desktop:~$ sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc

Then, Insert Java home as path to JDK location and ANT home as path ANT location as mentioned below at the end of bash file. I entered path for locations according to my machine.

```
  export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
 set path=$path $ANT_HOME/bin
```

Eventually, save and close the file. If you configured correctly, the terminal must show following note with the command 
    “ant –version”.

```
      xxx@xxx-desktop:~$ ant -version
```

Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on November 10 2008
It means configuration is Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's standard practice to omit the trailing slash when setting env variables on *nix. (You have a trailing slash at the end of yours). So you should write:

export ANT_HOME=/opt/apache/ant/1.8.4/apache-ant-1.8.4

... and not:

export ANT_HOME=/opt/apache/ant/1.8.4/apache-ant-1.8.4/

~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile are good if you only care about *your* user account *and* you use the bash shell. For setting an environment variable, it doesn't really make much difference which of these you use. .bashrc would reset it every time you opened a new shell, whereas .bash_profile would reset it every time you logged-in.

The files in /etc would set it for *all* users on your system (but it could be overridden locally). If you're going to have different users building and you want them all to have the same environment varilables, then /etc/profile would be a good place to put it.

Comment: Warning: at least with Ant 1.7.1, omitting the trailing slash like this will cause Ant to fail to load libraries. I'm not even joking; see also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=490542

Answer (score 1):

To read the variable from java, use `System.getenv().get("ANT_HOME")`. Read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html).

As for where to set it, I prefer using ~/.bashrc, unless you're going to run your program from other users, or with `sudo`. Then you should use `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 1):

I'd prerer to put all environment variables to different file and `source` it from `$HOME/.xsessionrc`. `.xsessionrc` is simply a shell script which is executed after the new X session by login manager like gdm, kdm or so.

Answer (score 1):

## BEST way to set environment variables GLOBALY

**Step 1 :** 
Set all variables in `/etc/environment` like this

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
ANT_HOME=/usr/....<path to ant home>
set path="/usr/bin:<path2>:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

**Step 2 :** 
Add this line at the end of `~/.bashrc` of each user

```
source /etc/environment
```

**Step 3 :** 
Execute the following command to make the changes.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Hope it helps..!!