# Why do Golang environment variables keep disappearing when I log in as root on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, environment

Why do golang environment variables keep disappearing when I log in as root?
I have to run `source ~/.profile` each time I want to use it which is not the case with a simple user. What is wrong with this?

**Installation steps**

```
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo apt update
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo echo 'PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"' >> ~/.profile    
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile
k4@k4sec:~$ source ~/.profile
k4@k4sec:~$ go version
go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo -s
root@k4sec:~# go version
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install golang-go
root@k4sec:~# source ~/.profile
root@k4sec:~# go version
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install golang-go
root@k4sec:~# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile
root@k4sec:~# source ~/.profile
root@k4sec:~# go version
go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
root@k4sec:~# exit
exit
k4@k4sec:~$ go version
go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
k4@k4sec:~$ sudo -s
root@k4sec:~# go version
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install golang-go
root@k4sec:~#
```

**GO env**

```
k4@k4sec:~$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/k4/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/k4/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/k4/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build611508695=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: Environment variables (as the name suggest) configure an environment and each user has a different one. The shel you run with `-s` simply doesn't read /etc/profile on startup.

Comment: Long story short: different users have their environment set up using different sources. Your normal user and root are different users, so they have their environment set up differently. [More details](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set ANT\_HOME on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224804/how-to-set-ant-home-on-ubuntu-desktop-12-04)

Comment: why the user environments don't disappear only the root ones? I installed golang the same way for both users, and I set up the global environments

Comment: @Baziwe: From the [sudo man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) : *The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.*

Comment: thanks all, the `sudo -s` was the bad way to use the root mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try setting the environments variables as mentioned in this link - https://techknowbase.com/how-to-setup-install-golang-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I tried this as well as a user, It did work for the user but not for root, and then I tried to use the same procedure as root, it worked, but when I log out and log in again, it stops. Kinda weird

Comment: try out setting variables with sudo -E su. To create persistent variables that are truly system-wide, you should set them in /etc/environment.

Comment: thanks, the `sudo -s` was the bad way to use the root mode